# Facebook custom share button

Tags: php, html, css, facebook, share

Im looking for a simple Facebook share button that will open a new browser window and share the current page URL.

This was simple with Twitter using:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?text=Specced%20-" class="twitter" target="_blank"></a>
```

Im looking for something very similar for Facebook however it seems like with Facebook it is made purposely more difficult than it could be.

I have tried at least 10 different ways and always get the same error:

Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

I am already including the Facebook web API below the first body tag.... I have also gone into Facebook developer settings and correctly setup eve tying by entering the root domain I intend to share

Thankyou for any help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the old simple sharer

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href),'facebook-share-dialog','width=626,height=436');return false;">Share on Facebook</a>
```